# What are the steps to successfully connect into a HTTPS website

Tags: android, https, android-2.3-gingerbread

I am having problems for the pass 2 days with this HTTPS connection issue for quite sometime and have already searched online for solutions. I have come across SSLSocketFactory and tried to use it, only to find out that I can't solve my problems. I do not get any SSL errors on loading HTTPS, but rather I get a white screen with no load.

What I would like to know is this, I start a new Android project. Add only a `WebView` into the **main.xml**, then I do a `loadURL(https website)`. Which returned a white screen with no SSL errors. What are the steps am I required to do before I can view what is displayed on the HTTPS website I am trying to access? Is there a need to use 3rd party APIs? JAR files I can download?

**EDIT:** I didn't get any SSL Errors. I only sees this: `request time failed: java.net.SocketException: Address family not supported by protocol`. Any idea how I am to approach this?

Answer (score 1):

Overriding method to your WebViewClient implementation,

```
@Override
public void onReceivedSslError(WebView view, SslErrorHandler handler, SslError error) {
    handler.proceed(); // Ignore SSL certificate errors
}
```

Try the following code, https working for me,

```
package org.example.webviewdemo;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.View.OnKeyListener;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class WebViewDemo extends Activity {
    private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
    }
    private WebView webView;
    private EditText urlField;

    private Button goButton;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        // Create reference to UI elements
        webView  = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview_compontent);
        urlField = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.url);
        goButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.go_button);

        // workaround so that the default browser doesn't take over
        webView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());

        // Setup click listener
        goButton.setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                openURL();
            }
        });

        // Setup key listener
        urlField.setOnKeyListener( new OnKeyListener() {
            public boolean onKey(View view, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                if(keyCode==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER) {
                    openURL();
                    return true;
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        });

    }

    /** Opens the URL in a browser */
    private void openURL() {
        webView.loadUrl(urlField.getText().toString());
        webView.requestFocus();
    }    
}
```

main.xml

```
<LinearLayout 
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <EditText  
    android:id="@+id/url" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"     
    android:lines="1"
    android:layout_weight="1.0" android:hint="http://"/>

    <Button
    android:id="@+id/go_button"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"     
    android:text="@string/go_button"
    />

</LinearLayout>

<WebView  
    android:id="@+id/webview_compontent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_weight="1.0"   
/>
```

Comment: Not working, but instead of getting a white screen. Now I see Web page not available.

Comment: Nope, still not working... I just enquired from my web administrator, he informed me that he is using a self-signed certificate. From the looks from your codes, can it also authenticate self-signed sites?

Comment: did u add the <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> in your manifest file ?

Comment: I didn't just now, but when I did. It gave me a white screen.

Comment: Visit the following link, Android   http://marakana.com/forums/android/examples/58.html

Comment: That website is what you answered and it is a Customer Web Browser. I am not doing a Custom Web Browser..